# mobile html radio button text size scales with orientation

Tags: html, text, radio-button, label, font-size

nearly I have radio buttons in my WebView app (WebKIt, Safari on iOS) whose label text size I'd like to preserve when switching orientation of the iDevice. I start in portrait mode, and explicitly state the text size for the label, yet when I rotate the device to landscape mode the label size doubles, despite the font size specification.

Oddly, ordinary text lines keep their size; only the radio button labels scale with orientation. If I set the text size on one of two buttons in a row, the first one honors the spec, and the second one scales.

Code:

```
<span style="font-size:16px">Pick a Name</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="range" value="Bob!">
<span style="font-size:12px;">Bob!</span>
<input type="radio" id="range" value="Fred!">
<span style="font-size:12px;">Fred!</span>
```

Now imagine that the "Pick a Name" string is the same size on each orientation; it and the button (and text) remain the same size. Bob! and Fred! labels double in size.

Crap - I need 10 rep points to post images.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have added ID to your span for both Bob! and Fred!

```
<span style="font-size:16px">Pick a Name</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="range" value="Bob!">
<span id = "bob" style="font-size:12px;">Bob!</span>
<input type="radio" id="range" value="Fred!">
<span id = "fred" style="font-size:12px;">Fred!</span>
```

When changing orientation it is best to use css media query like so.

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) { 
     #bob {
         font-size: 12px;
     }
     #fred {
         font-size: 12px;
     }
}
```

This should preserve the size of the Bob! and Fred! text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added code to the original post. Couldn't post images yet for want of rep points.

Comment: hopefully new updated edit helps you.. If not please share more code and information to your question as this is a standard way of handling orientation